# Does key exist before updating the value of that key?

Tags: go

In the below code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

// scores holds values incremented by multiple goroutines.
var scores = make(map[string]int)

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(2)

    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
            if _, ok := scores["A"]; !ok {
                scores["A"] = 1
            } else {
                scores["A"]++
            }
        }
        wg.Done()
    }()

    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
            scores["B"]++ // Line 28
        }
        wg.Done()
    }()

    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("Final scores:", scores)
}
```

---

Above code has data race on `scores`, but,

Line 28 does not give runtime error for instruction `scores["B"]++`.

How `scores["B"]++` at Line 28, able to update value for key(`"B"`) for `i=0`? because key(`"B"`) does not exist in the map `scores`

Comment: The go runtime does not automatically generate runtime errors for race conditions. You must use the race detector. This code will trigger the race detector every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you familiar [with the default (zero) value semantics of Go maps](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value)?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var scores = make(map[string]int)
    scores["B"]++
    fmt.Println(scores)
}
```

[Check this snippet on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/rfXiFq0tp8Z).

---

Read about maps here: https://blog.golang.org/maps